# How can I check if someone has voted for my discord bot in dblpy?

Tags: discord.py

My discord bot recently got accepted to top.gg, but I can't properly wrap my head around the documentation for dblpy. How can I check if someone has voted for my bot in the past 12hr to use certain commands? I would appreciate if anyone could help, because im not even sure how to connect to the API. Thanks everyone.

Comment: https://dblpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#dbl.DBLClient.get_user_vote

Create a new cog in your discord bot like shown in the examples on the dblpy repo then inside the cog create a command or listener which uses the `get_user_vote` method to ping the api

Comment: Adding on to @Genetical, you might not want to have it always checking for every command because you may get rate-limited. Instead do something like adding the user to a list of users who have voted and have a scheduler such as
`await asyncio.sleep(43200)
#probably better way to do this`
and remove them from the list after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_dbl_vote(self, data):
    user = data['user']
    embed = discord.Embed(description="New Vote! Voter: {}".format(user))
    channel = self.bot.get_channel(int(ID))
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```